# xcconfig files with XCode9 for PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER

Tags: xcode9, xcodebuild, xcconfig

Until now, we were using the xccofnig file per scheme to select the proper provisioning profiles. For example the "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER" was set to different value in each of the scheme specific xcconfig file and them "xcodebuild" would just work fine by picking up the correct profile based on the xccofnig set for that scheme.

In XCode 9 this is not working and it looks like we need to set "provisioningProfiles" in exportOptionsPlist file. Does this mean that the xcconfig files can no more be used to set the correct profile anymore and we have to use this profile selection in exportOptionsPlist only?

Thanks.